# "No module named X" error even with sys.path.append

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

so I have a project with this directory structure:

```
app
  |
  __init__.py
  some_python.py
scripts
  |
  some_script.py
```

I want to import a function from some_python.py in some_script.py, so I use this in some_script.py

```
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(os.path.realpath(__file__))
print(path)
print(str(path.parent.parent.absolute()) + "/app")
sys.path.append(str(path.parent.parent.absolute()) + "/app")
print(sys.path)
```

I can see from printing sys.path that the app directory is the last item in the path. but I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` when I run `some_script.py`

I tried adding the app directory to the path, and I expected that to make python find the module. However, it did not.

Comment: if the module is in a nested folder (subfolder) then an absolute path is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

if the folder is a nested folder (sub folder) as is given in the question, then the absolute path is not necessary.

```py
# subfolders are visible and use dot notation
import scripts.some_script
```

if the folder is **not** a subfolder, then the absolute path would need to be used.

however, using `path = Path(os.path.realpath(__file__))` takes you to the folder of the executable and all nested folders. So you need to be careful with the path.

To be unambiguous copy and paste the full path if you are going with this option, like this:

```
full_path = c:\\python\\tests\\full_path\\file_name.py
```

(including double backslash or single forward slash for windows).

Comment: it is in a sibling folder, not a sub folder

Comment: yes,  that is what i thought.  The code in the question navigates to the subfolder so an absolute path or make sure that a proper relative folder is schieved.

Comment: generally speaking, i always keep to the same folder or children folders which works well in python. i am sure there are cases where on needs alternatives (hence the above).

Answer (score 0):

To import a Python module from a sibling folder, you need to modify the `sys.path` list to include the path to the sibling folder. However, it's generally better to use relative imports or transform your project into a package.

To import a sibling module function you can use a relative import:

```py
# some_script.py
from app.some_python import Test

Test()
```

some_python.py:

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        print('Hi from some_python.py')
```

Running `some_script.py` will yield an error:
`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

To get around the Error, use the **sys.path** approach to temporarily modify the Python path:

```py
# some_script.py
import sys
sys.path.append('../app')
from app.some_python import Test

Test()
```

This works nicely from PyCharm. PyCharm adds project root folder to the `sys.path`.

Let's change the script to adopt for standalone invocation from `shell/cmd` by adding project root folder to the `sys.path`:

```py
# some_script.py
import os
import sys

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(f'Current folder: {cwd}')

app = os.path.abspath('..\\app')
if os.path.isdir('app'):
    sys.path.append(cwd)
else:
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(f'{cwd}/..'))

if os.path.isdir(app):
    sys.path.append(app)

print(f'sys.path: {"\n  ".join(sys.path)}')
from app.some_python import Test

Test()
```

Run from project root folder:

```bash
python scripts\some_script.py
```

Run from scripts folder:

```bash
python some_script.py
```

In my opinion I would argue this is all but elegant, I would avoid structuring my code this way.

Comment: I switched over to just `sys.path.append('../app')`, but I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: Indeed, I was using PyCharm project to test and PyCharm adds project root to the sys.path by default. See the updated answer.